# mozcjpeg - optimize original image

Tags: bash, mozjpeg

I'm trying to optimize sample.jpg with mozcjpeg, but I want it to compress sample.jpg, and not creating another file.

I run this command:

```
mozcjpeg -quality 80 sample.jpg > sample.jpg
```

and I get

```
Empty input file
```

What's the right way to do it?

P.S. I have a bash script that runs once a day to optimize images created in the last 24 hours.

Answer (score 2):

`anycmd foo.jpg > foo.jpg` is understood as:

- The shell will open `foo.jpg` for write (overwriting any existing data).
- The shell will fork and set this open file as the stdout.
- The shell will exec `anycmd foo.jpg`.

So, by the time the command is executed, the original file is already gone. How can you work around that?

Well, you can create a temporary file, [as suggested in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54858295).

Alternatively, you can use `sponge`. It's part of [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) package.

```
$ whatis sponge
sponge (1)           - soak up standard input and write to a file
```

This tool allows you to write:

```
mozcjpeg -quality 80 sample.jpg | sponge sample.jpg
```

It works because `sponge` will first read all of the stdin (in memory), and only after stdin reaches EOF it will open the file for writing.

Answer (score 1):

You’re reading the file and overwriting it at the same time. Instead, make an intermediary file:

```
tmp_file="$(mktemp)"
mozcjpeg -quality 80 sample.jpg > "${tmp_file}"
mv "${tmp_file}" sample.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a different output file name, otherwise it gets immediately overwritten.

Comment: Vadim, I need to overwrite original file, that's what the question is about. jpegtran can do that, so I think mozjpeg can do it too.